# UnicodeDecodeError for invalid sequence beyond requested read

Tags: python, character-encoding

Suppose I write a UTF-8 encoded string to a file, followed by a byte sequence that is invalid in UTF-8:

```py
with open('/tmp/foo.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('αβγ'.encode('utf-8'))
    f.write(b'\x80')  # will cause unicode parse error if read
```

If I read exactly 3 UTF-8-encoded characters from this file, it should be fine, right?

```py
with open('/tmp/foo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read(3))
```

But actually it raises an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

Why is it trying to decode more than it needs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This is because python decodes a chunk of the file in advance, even if you never end up reading that far into it.

##### Explanation

I tried adding more valid characters before the invalid character to see how python would handle it, and sure enough, adding enough valid characters before the invalid character silenced that error. I then looked for the magic number of padding characters you needed, and it ended up being 8192, or 2^13. Here's a script that might give you a better idea of what's going on:

```
chunk_size = 2 ** 13
print(f'chunk size: {chunk_size}')

padding_sizes = [chunk_size-1, chunk_size, chunk_size+1]

for padding_size in padding_sizes:
    with open(f'/tmp/{padding_size}.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(('a'*padding_size).encode('utf-8'))
        f.write(b'\x80')  # will cause unicode parse error if read

for padding_size in padding_sizes:
    print()
    print(f'number of padding bytes: {padding_size}')
    for num_bytes in [1, padding_size, padding_size+1]:
        print(f'reading {num_bytes:4} bytes: ', end='')
        try:
            with open(f'/tmp/{padding_size}.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.read(num_bytes)
                print('PASS')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print('FAIL')
```

And the output:

```
chunk size: 8192

number of padding bytes: 8191
reading    1 bytes: FAIL
reading 8191 bytes: FAIL
reading 8192 bytes: FAIL

number of padding bytes: 8192
reading    1 bytes: PASS
reading 8192 bytes: PASS
reading 8193 bytes: FAIL

number of padding bytes: 8193
reading    1 bytes: PASS
reading 8193 bytes: PASS
reading 8194 bytes: FAIL
```

Even reading a single byte of a file with an invalid character in the first chunk results in an error, whereas reading an entire chunk of a file in which the invalid character is the very next byte raises no error. And, as expected, attempting to read the invalid byte always raises an error.

**But why?** Probably because most times you read from a file, you'll read thousands of bytes. And while decoding bytes is probably a pretty cheap operation, the overhead of constantly going back to the file, decoding a small number of bytes, and storing the results could become pretty significant if done thousands of times.

##### Bonus

Interestingly, when using `chunk_size + 1` padding bytes, reading `chunk_size + 1` bytes raises no error. Out of curiosity, I added an extra test case:

```
print(f'number of padding bytes: {chunk_size+1}')
print(f'reading {chunk_size} bytes, then 1 byte: ', end='')
try:
    with open(f'/tmp/{chunk_size+1}.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.read(chunk_size)
        f.read(1)
        print('PASS')
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print('FAIL')
```

And the output:

```
number of padding bytes: 8193
reading 8192 bytes, then 1 byte: FAIL
```

This seems to suggest that each call to `f.read()` will decode *at least* a chunk of bytes from the file (if those bytes haven't been decoded already by a previous call to `f.read()`), but it can also decode more, and not just in multiples of chunks.

Comment: Yes, I guess that since the file is buffered, Python will opportunistically try to read *and decode* more. It must handle the case where you have a multi-byte character encoded across the 8192 byte boundary?

Comment: @rgov definitely seems like it, just gave it a test by encoding the `˖` character (two bytes) across the boundary and it seems to work totally fine! Interesting though, it must keep track of the fact that it has a byte that it *has* read but *hasn't* decoded yet